# BEM naming issues

Tags: css, bem

Recently I have started using BEM in my project to organize CSS but now I am up to the point where i have html like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="container__header">
      <div>TITLE</div>
      <div>SUBTITLE</div>
   </div>
   <div class="container__body">
   </div>
</div>
```

As I am more familiar with SMACSS I treat container with header and body as layout related styles. But then content of header on each subpage will differ, sometimes it will have title/subtitle that need different styling sometimes it will be some completly different structure. In terms of SMACSS I would put it in module folder and manage there but now with BEM would be it good practice to now create element such as note-header that will have elements __title and __subtitle?

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="container__header note-header">
      <div class="note-header__title">TITLE</div>
      <div class="note-header__subtitle">SUBTITLE</div>
   </div>
   <div class="container__body note-body">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem I have with this approach is that note-header will most of the time probably be empty class just for the sake of naming convention. What is best practice to handle such case

Comment: It's good article for naming -> https://medium.com/fed-or-dead/battling-bem-5-common-problems-and-how-to-avoid-them-5bbd23dee319

Answer (score 0):

I personally use three types of elements, namely:

> `l-` prefixed **layout** elements, such as containers, headers, footers.
>
> `b-` prefixed **block** elements, such as a menu, a small header inside a layout, etc.
>
> `c-` prefixed **component** elements, such as buttons, links etc.

This in conjunction with modifiers say: `c-button--white` and `c-button--black` works fine.

Consider the following structure for your example:

```
<div class="l-container">
   <div class="b-note">
      <div class="b-note__title">TITLE</div>
      <div class="b-note__subtitle">SUBTITLE</div>
      <div class="b-note__content">
          <div class="c-button">
              <button class="c-button__button">Submit</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="b-slideshow">
          <div class="b-slideshow__title"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

In my projects, it's vital to make sure general styling is separate. Therefore I try to minimise any blocks / classes being used throughout other elements. This avoids styling drama later on because you're using `b-note-header__title` somewhere else as well, that requires just a small adjustment, but changing the main rule messes up your other titles.